# How to make nodes to be aware that they were added to menu programatically

Tags: 7, routes, rules

I'm adding nodes to menu programatically by custom PHP snippet in Rules. The problem is that nodes aren't aware of this - so the option "Provide a menu link" is unchecked in them, even if their menu-item exists. I cannot find anything relevant in $node object. How to fix this?

My code is:

```
$node_path = "node/" . $node->nid;
$node_alias = drupal_get_path_alias($node_path);
$menu = menu_load_links('main-menu');

foreach($menu as $key=>$value) {
    if($node_alias == $menu[$key]['link_path'] || $node_path == $menu[$key]['link_path']) {
        return;
    }
    if($menu[$key]['link_title'] == $node->field_rok['und'][0]['value'] && $menu[$key]['link_path'] == "<nolink>") {
        $menu_year = $menu[$key]['mlid'];
    }
    if($menu[$key]['link_path'] == "archiwum") {
        $archiwum_plid = $menu[$key]['mlid'];
    }
}

if(!isset($archiwum_plid)) {
    return;
}

if(!isset($menu_year)) {
    $item = array(
        'link_path' => '<nolink>',
        'link_title' => $node->field_rok['und'][0]['value'],
        'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
        'plid' => $archiwum_plid,
        'hidden' => 0,
    );
    // menu_edit_item_validate(array(), $item); Drupal doesn't recognize this function in this place (Rules), don't know why... :/
    $menu_year = menu_link_save($item);
}

$item = array(
    'link_path' => $node_alias,
    'link_title' => $node->field_numer_w_roku['und'][0]['value'] . '/' . $node->field_rok['und'][0]['value'] .' (' . $node->field_numer['und'][0]['value'] . ')',
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    'plid' => $menu_year,
    'hidden' => 0,
);

// menu_edit_item_validate(array(), $item);
menu_link_save($item);

menu_rebuild();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it - I had to use drupal_get_normal_path($node_alias) on path added to menu. I hope that will be helpful for someone.